# How do I get rid of None values in list? Python

Tags: python, json

I have API that returns JSON in response. I want to sort that JSON in Python.
Here is the part of JSON that I sort based on.

```
"event_dates": {
            "starting_day": "2020-12-05T11:00:00.000Z",
            "ending_day": null,
            "additional_description": null
        }
```

I got sorted that with

`sorted_data1 = sorted(data["data"],key=lambda x: x["event_dates"]["starting_day"] if x["event_dates"]["starting_day"] is not None else str(0))`

but there are None types sorted in the beginning of list because of else str(0). Is there way to skip None type values so they are not in sorted list? Also if you have suggestions on improving the sorting function I would be grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter the values out before sorting.

```
sorted_data1 = sorted((x for x in data["data"] if x["event_dates"]["starting_day"] is not None),key=lambda x: x["event_dates"]["starting_day"])
```